# png transparency and supersleight

Tags: png

I want to make the transparent `.png` images work correctly in ie 5.5 and 6, and found supersleight recommended (http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).

it works well on both static and hover images, showing the images how they are intended to be shown, but its not quite perfect, ie 5.5+6 think that the image has failed to load, so shows the image `alt` text.

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother trying to make fixes for IE 5.5 and IE 6. These 2 browsers are the worst of all the currently used browsers - they almost completely break basic HTML and web standards. They are also 10 and 11 years old respectively - ancient, a millenium in computing terms.

Also, trying to implement support/fixes for these browsers is counter-productive to the spirit of technology, the web and most importantly your own time. We need to advance, not keep ourselves stuck in the past.

Let IE 5.5 and IE6 users enjoy the crappy experience on their crappy browsers. We are in the information age, the age of computers. There should be no excuse for using IE 5 or IE 6, period!

Don't fix it!

Comment: @john - comments shouldn't be posted as another answer. You can add a comment to my existing answer, as I've done here.

Comment: Also, don't you see the conundrum? The more people invest in trying to "squeeze out as much as we can" from IE 6 users, the longer they will stick around, and the worse it is for the rest of us. 7.5%? Pffft! I say nuke their asses! I've already done so.